# Ubuntu 16.04 Server Network Delay

Tags: 16.04

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 server standard and when booting without a network cable plugged in it takes almost 5 minutes for the system to boot. Is there a way to make this so it only retries to get an answer from the DHCP server once instead of multiple times. Thanks in advance for any help on this issue.

Adam

Comment: For my purposes I was able to edit the file networking.service located in the following directory. /etc/systemd/system/network-online.target.wants. Then edit the following line:
TimeoutStartSec=5min

I set mine to 1min and it fixed my issue.